# Showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+c}-x\right)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

A limit I had to compute recently boiled down to the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+c}-x\right)=0\quad\mbox{for $c\ge0$}$$

How can I show that this limit is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that \begin{gather*}
\sqrt{x^2+c}-x=(\sqrt{x^2+c}-x)\frac{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}\\
=\frac{x^2-x^2+c}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}\\
=\frac{c}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}
\end{gather*}

Comment: Furthermore, this should be in two cases. One for if $c=0$ where, the limit is easily computable. And one for $c\neq 0$ where we have the above. Then you can argue that this is true since the denominator does not vanish anywhere.

Comment: I feel dumb now.

Comment: @FUZxxl Everything is obvious when you know the answer!

Comment: I don't see whay a separate discussion when $c=0$ is necessary. This looks true whenever $x^2 \ge |c|$.

Comment: @martycohen I would argue $\sqrt{x^2+c}-x\neq \frac{c}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}$ when $c=0$, as for $x=0$ there is an obvious problem.

Comment: But only for $x=0$. Anyway, the OP's question has $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @martycohen You're right. Haha I'm silly

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**
$$\sqrt{x^2+c} - x = \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that for positive $x$ we have 
$$x\le \sqrt{x^2+c}\le x+\frac{c}{2x}.$$
This is because 
$$\left(x+\frac{c}{2x}\right)^2=x^2+c+\frac{c^2}{4x^2}\ge x^2+c.$$
Thus 
$$0\le \sqrt{x^2+c}-x\le \frac{c}{2x}.$$
Now Squeeze.

Comment: That was slick.

Comment: I thought I would write it that way to emphasize "size estimates." Your multiply by a version of the conjugate is a very useful technique.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

$$\sqrt{x^2+c}=|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{c}{x^2}} = |x|(1+\frac{c}{2x^2} + o(\frac{c}{x^2}))$$

Answer (score 1):

something you might notice that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2 + c} = x$ is trivially true for positive and negative finite values of c.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2 + c} -\lim_{x\to\infty}x = U$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x-\lim_{x\to\infty}x = U$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x -\lim_{x\to\infty}x = 0$$
perhaps not the most mathematically rigorous argument, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{ x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+c}-x & =\lim_{ x \to \infty}(\sqrt{x^2+c}-x)\frac{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}\\
&=\lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{x^2-x^2+c}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x}\\
&=\lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{c}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+x} \\ & =0.
\end{align*}